# How to capture arguments with io.mockk in unit-test

Tags: kotlin, mockk

[image]I am having difficulties when trying to use a CapturingSlot<*> from mockk.

I get the error message shown in the above image

See the paragraph named Capturing in https://mockk.io

As explained in the user guide, I have tried `val car = mockk<Car>()` but also `val car: CapturingSlot<Car> = slot()` but both attempts results in the error message listet above...

Anyone with suggestions?

This is a compile-time error and I am using the following dependency in my Gradle build file: testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk-jvm:1.13.8")

Comment: Capturing certainly works.  Can you provide more code, specifically how you setup the mock and how you are declaring and then using the Slot

Comment: hmmm... when writing an example of my code, I realised that the capturing is done in a every {} block, while I was trying to do this in the verify {} block...

Comment: So solved.  Good.

Comment: no.... it stills give me headaches... the compilation occurs when declaring the slot in the junit-test-method: `val some = slot<Some>()`

Answer (score 0):

Jactor-rises, maybe some example code will help:

In this specimen code, imagine that `consumer` is the code under test.  It takes 3 args and during it operation it will make call to `someApi.someCall(...)` with 3 arguments and you want to check the middle one contains the expected data:

```
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.slot
import io.mockk.verify

val analysisSlot = slot<Analysis>()
every { someApi.someCall(SET_ID, capture(analysisSlot), any()) } returns mockk()

consumer.accept(questionSet, authHeaders(), mockk())

analysisSlot.captured shouldBe Analysis(
    ...
)
verify {
    channelsomeApi.someCall(any(), any(), any())
}
```